# How to identify monitors by EDID?

Tags: multiple-monitors, vesa, edid

My company has so many monitors and HDMI repeaters. So, I want to distinguish and identify those display devices so that a Linux host can detect which monitor/repeater is connected.

Although a Linux host can get EDID from `/sys/class/drm/*/edid`, I'm not sure how to identify monitors/repeaters.

1. As long as an EDID data has not been overridden, is it constant forever ?

   If so, all I have to do is to collect every EDID binary files (or hashed signatures derived from EDID binaries). If such EDID specification or standard exits, can you tell me ?

   I worry that some monitors may change its EDID content when some mode(ex. resolution, rotation) are changed. Transient identifier is useless.
2. Can I derive an unique identifier data from an EDID ?

   If EDID may change, I have to derive an unique identifier data from an EDID binary.
   According to [EDID specification](https://glenwing.github.io/docs/VESA-EEDID-A2.pdf), EDID binary has some identifier fields.

   - Manufacturer ID (in header)
   - product code (in header)
   - serial number (in header)
   - Display Product Serial Number (in Display Descriptor)

   But both serial number and Display Product Serial Number are optional. Is there any way to derive a correct unique identifier from an EDID binary ?